# Calculating values as percent changes based on unique ID and dates

Tags: r

I have a dataset with repeated measurements that are tagged by unique ID and date. For each measurement I want to create a data frame that calculates the percent change from the the first measurement for all subsequent measurements for each unique ID ie. the Jan 2,3 and 4 values for A are divided by the Jan 1 value for A. This is very easy to do in Excel using sticky formulas but am struggling with an R solution.

Here is a sample dataset:

```
values <- rnorm(12, 30, 5)
ID <- rep(c('A', 'B', 'C'), 4)
dates <- rep(as.Date(c("2019-01-01", "2019-01-02", "2019-01-03", "2019-01- 04")), 3)

dat <- data.frame(values, ID, dates)

     values ID      dates
  36.96190  A 2019-01-01
  22.44808  B 2019-01-01
  28.82219  C 2019-01-01
  18.50368  A 2019-01-02
  22.19817  B 2019-01-02
  33.77493  C 2019-01-02
  32.20991  A 2019-01-03
  28.80391  B 2019-01-03
  26.33285  C 2019-01-03
  31.87512  A 2019-01-04
  26.07043  B 2019-01-04
  22.17923  C 2019-01-04
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could do this easily using `dplyr`, first by arranging the dates and then dividing the `values` with the `first` `value` by group (`ID`).

```
library(dplyr)

dat %>%
  arrange(dates) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(ratio = values/first(values))
```

OR

```
dat %>%
  arrange(dates) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(ratio = values/values[1L])


#   values ID    dates      ratio
#    <dbl> <fct> <date>     <dbl>
# 1   24.0 A     2019-01-01 1    
# 2   32.1 B     2019-01-01 1    
# 3   27.2 C     2019-01-01 1    
# 4   31.4 B     2019-01-02 0.976
# 5   32.5 C     2019-01-02 1.20 
# 6   25.5 A     2019-01-02 1.07 
# 7   35.4 C     2019-01-03 1.30 
# 8   27.1 A     2019-01-03 1.13 
# 9   27.6 B     2019-01-03 0.859
#10   18.3 A     2019-01-04 0.762
#11   27.3 B     2019-01-04 0.848
#12   25.0 C     2019-01-04 0.920
```

---

A base R approach using `ave`, here we get the minimum row index for each `ID` and then divide the corresponding `values` with the `values` in the group.

```
dat$ratio <- with(dat, values/values[ave(order(dates), ID, FUN = min)])

dat
#     values ID      dates     ratio
#1  23.96467  A 2019-01-01 1.0000000
#2  31.38715  B 2019-01-02 0.9764050
#3  35.42221  C 2019-01-03 1.3033536
#4  18.27151  A 2019-01-04 0.7624353
#5  32.14562  B 2019-01-01 1.0000000
#6  32.53028  C 2019-01-02 1.1969457
#7  27.12630  A 2019-01-03 1.1319287
#8  27.26684  B 2019-01-04 0.8482287
#9  27.17774  C 2019-01-01 1.0000000
#10 25.54981  A 2019-01-02 1.0661449
#11 27.61404  B 2019-01-03 0.8590294
#12 25.00807  C 2019-01-04 0.9201673
```

**data**

```
set.seed(1234)
values <- rnorm(12, 30, 5)
ID <- rep(c('A', 'B', 'C'), 4)
dates <- rep(as.Date(c("2019-01-01", "2019-01-02", "2019-01-03", "2019-01- 04")), 3)
dat <- data.frame(values, ID, dates)
```